# Using output from Imagemagik page count, 02%d, to run php while loop

Tags: php, image-processing

I have Imagemagik installed on the server I'm using and I've successfully got it to split multipage PDF's into separate png images however I'm a little stick on the next step of the filing system;

For a quick overview, I'm creating an interface which allows users to upload documents and provide additional supporting information for the documents, the catch being the documents needed to be visible as thumbnails and mouse over images once uploaded and we have no control over the file format which the documents are uploaded in.

I've setup a whitelist of allowed file formats for security by dismantling the string name and reading the file extension.  I'm then using the Imagemagik convert function;

```
    exec("convert -density 200x200 -quality 100 images/test_folder/test.pdf images/test_folder/test_%02d.png");
```

To change PDF's into a format which can be displayed on screen.

What I want to do next, is use the numeric value created by the %02d string to initiate a php dowhile loop so I can run a function to insert links to each of the images into a database to be used as part of the interface.  However I have no ides where to go from this point, I don't really want to use ghost script as the conversion process is already running slowly so I'm trying to avoid running anything else which is data hungry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would glob that directory for png files:

```
$pngFiles = glob('images/test_folder/*.png');
foreach ($pngFiles as $pngFile) {
   preg_match('/(\d{2,})\.png$/i', $pngFile, $matches);
   $imgNum = (int) $matches[1];
   $imgName = basename($pngFile);
}
```